# Which texts are good for beginners to understand evolution on the genetic scope?

Tags: evolution, genetics, literature

Are there good texts to study the evolution, how it works, and how mutations and changes lead to evolution of the organism ?

And how does the information increase through the long time using mutations and other mechanisms?

Can you recommend specific texts?

Comment: what level are you looking for; popular science for the general public, high school level, undergraduate, graduate in graphic design, graduate in evolutionary genetics? you say beginner but beginner at what level?

Comment: having looked at your profile I see you are a high school student, I'd suggest heading towards Dawkins' popular science texts first, then Ridley's evolution for some finer detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Books on my shelf right now (I'm an evolutionary genetics grad student)...**

*Entry level:*

Evolution - Mark Ridley (not Matt Ridley)

A primer of ecological genetics - Connor & Hartl

*Intermediate:*

Elements of evolutionary genetics -  Charlesworth & Charlesworth

*Advanced:*

Principles of Population genetics - Hartl & Clark

Introduction to quantitative genetics - Falconer & Mackay

**Further basic/popular-science books include R Dawkins' Selfish Gene/The Extended Phenotype/The Greatest Show on Earth and of course The Origin of Species by Darwin**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to previous answers. For basic textbooks I've been happy with (earlier editions of):

- [*Evolution*, Futuyma](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1605351156)
- [*Genetics: From Genes to Genomes*, Hartwell et al.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007352526X)

EDIT:
I should also mention the free pdf book [*Theoretical Evolutionary Genetics* by Joe Felsenstein](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/pgbook/pgbook.html), with latest update from 2013. He uses it for a course in population gentics. So far, I have only browsed it myself. It is fairly math-heavy, but I thought that it could be of general interest.