# Math backbone in biology/genetic

Tags: genetics, theoretical-biology

Are there any good books, that shows some advanced models in genetics particularly?
The problem is i don't see any good math model in genetics interactions exept combinatorics. I'd like to know what else math structures and rules are there in genetics. 
I'd like create strong math backbone for better understanding genetics, but i can't find any advanced reliable sources for that. Are there any books that could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If population genetics is what interests you (but I don't think it is), then you should have a look at [Book recommendation on population/evolutionary genetics?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/book-recommendation-on-population-evolutionary-genetics) and [Mathematical Modelling of Natural Selection](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/mathematical-modelling-of-natural-selection/).

Comment: It would help us to understand exactly what you are looking for if you could link to a specific paper which you would like their work to be reported in the book.

Comment: Elements of Evolutionary Genetics; Charlesworth and Charlesworth

Comment: I would vote to close as unclear (but I cannot because apparently I already did and then retracted my vote). I do not know exactly what you are looking for. Adding an example of the type of study that you would like to find in your book would help.

Comment: Related/ possible duplicate of: [*A free book/resource for learning genetics?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35007/3624) and [*Which texts are good for beginners to understand evolution on the genetic scope?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/8769/3624)